# Загрузка изображений Prestashop через php

Tags: php, prestashop

Необходимо создать продукты через файл PHP. Мне удалось добавить все данные о продукте кроме его фотографий (Создавал все через подключение к PhpMyAdmin). На просторах интернета нашел функцию которая добавляет изображения используя классы Престы.
Это часть кода из импорта:

```
$image = new Image();
$image->id_product = (int) $product->id;
$image->position = Image::getHighestPosition($product->id) + 1;
$image->cover =  true;
$image->add();
if (!copyImg($product->id, $image->id, $data["IMGURL"], 'products', !Tools::getValue('regenerate'))) {
    $image->delete();
}

function copyImg($id_entity, $id_image, $url, $entity = 'products', $regenerate = true) {
    $tmpfile = tempnam(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_, 'ps_import');
    $watermark_types = explode(',', Configuration::get('WATERMARK_TYPES'));


    switch ($entity) {
        default:
        case 'products':
            $image_obj = new Image($id_image);
            $path = $image_obj->getPathForCreation();
            break;
        case 'categories':
            $path = _PS_CAT_IMG_DIR_ . (int) $id_entity;
            break;
        case 'manufacturers':
            $path = _PS_MANU_IMG_DIR_ . (int) $id_entity;
            break;
        case 'suppliers':
            $path = _PS_SUPP_IMG_DIR_ . (int) $id_entity;
            break;
    }
    $url = str_replace(' ', '%20', trim($url));


    // Evaluate the memory required to resize the image: if it's too much, you can't resize it.
    if (!ImageManager::checkImageMemoryLimit($url))
        return false;


    // 'file_exists' doesn't work on distant file, and getimagesize makes the import slower.
    // Just hide the warning, the processing will be the same.
    if (Tools::copy($url, $tmpfile)) {
        ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $path . '.jpg');
        $images_types = ImageType::getImagesTypes($entity);


        if ($regenerate)
            foreach ($images_types as $image_type) {
                ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $path . '-' . stripslashes($image_type['name']) . '.jpg', $image_type['width'], $image_type['height']);
                if (in_array($image_type['id_image_type'], $watermark_types))
                    Hook::exec('actionWatermark', array('id_image' => $id_image, 'id_product' => $id_entity));
            }
    }
    else {
        unlink($tmpfile);
        return false;
    }
    unlink($tmpfile);
    return true;
}
```

Но я не до конца понимаю как его использовать, нужно подключить какие-то дополнительный файлы? И есть ли другой способ добавить фотографии в продукты Престы через свой собственный файл PHP (Все данные продукта у меня есть: ID/Название и тд)?

***UPD***

Немного разобрался и лучшим решением было создать свой модуль. Теперь продукт создается, но изображение продукта просто белый квадрат, а на сервере не появляется каталог который видно в ссылке если посмотреть через просмотр кода элемента этого ~белого квадрата~

Вот код модуля функции модуля которая отвечает за создание продукта:

```
public function processForm()
  {
      // Create or update product based on prodID
      $output = '';
  
      // Retrieve variables for product creation/update
      $prodID = 99999; // Example prodID
      $prodName = 'Sample Product'; // Example product name
      $prodPrice = 10.99; // Example product price
      $prodQuantity = 100; // Example product quantity
      $imageURL = 'юрл фото'; // Example image URL
      // Add more variables as needed
  
      // Check if product with given prodID already exists
      $existingProduct = new Product($prodID);
      $productExists = Validate::isLoadedObject($existingProduct);
  
      if ($productExists) {
          // Update existing product
          $existingProduct->name = $prodName;
          $existingProduct->price = $prodPrice;
          $existingProduct->quantity = $prodQuantity;
          // Remove existing product images
          $existingProduct->deleteImages();
          // Update product image
          if (!empty($imageURL)) {
              // Save image locally
              $localImagePath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/local_image.jpg';
              file_put_contents($localImagePath, file_get_contents($imageURL));
              // Add image to product
              $this->addProductImage($localImagePath, $prodID);
              // Delete local image after adding
              unlink($localImagePath);
          }
          // Update other product attributes as needed
          if ($existingProduct->save()) {
              $output .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Product updated successfully.'));
          } else {
              $output .= $this->displayError($this->l('Failed to update product.'));
          }
      } else {
          // Create new product
          $newProduct = new Product();
          $newProduct->name = $prodName;
          $newProduct->price = $prodPrice;
          $newProduct->quantity = $prodQuantity;
          // Set other product attributes as needed
          if ($newProduct->save()) {
              // Set product image
              if (!empty($imageURL)) {
                  // Save image locally
                  $localImagePath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/local_image.jpg';
                  file_put_contents($localImagePath, file_get_contents($imageURL));
                  // Add image to product
                  $this->addProductImage($localImagePath, $newProduct->id);
                  // Delete local image after adding
                  unlink($localImagePath);
              }
              $output .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('New product created successfully.'));
          } else {
              $output .= $this->displayError($this->l('Failed to create new product.'));
          }
      }
  
      return $output;
  }
  
  private function addProductImage($imagePath, $productId)
  {
      $image = new Image();
      $image->id_product = (int)$productId;
      $image->position = Image::getHighestPosition($productId) + 1;
      $image->cover = 1;
      if (!$image->add()) {
          return false;
      }
      // Load the image from the specified path
      $sourceImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);
      if (!$sourceImage) {
          return false;
      }
      // Get the image dimensions
      list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imagePath);
      // Create a new true color image with the size of the product image
      $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      // Copy and resize the source image to the new image
      if (!imagecopyresized($newImage, $sourceImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height)) {
          return false;
      }
      // Save the new image
      if (!imagejpeg($newImage, _PS_PROD_IMG_DIR_ . $productId . '-' . $image->id . '.jpg')) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
```